# ClassyTaxiServer with Server error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-play-developer-api, play-billing-library

I'm implementing the **ClassyTaxiAppKotlin** + **ClassyTaxiServer** project but without success.

I followed all the steps in the tutorial.

Apparently the **ClassyTaxiAppKotlin** android app is functional, processes the subscription purchase order and sends the information to the **CLOUD FUNCTIONS**, but does not receive the purchase registration/confirmation.

In my understanding, upon receiving the payment confirmation, **PLAY STORE** must send this confirmation to the **ClassyTaxiServer** server so that the server returns the registration/confirmation of the purchase and grants access to the **ClassyTaxiAppKotlin** application.

So when confirming payment in **ClassyTaxiAppKotlin** app, I notice that I get some logs in **firebase functions** from (instanceId_register_v2, realtime_notification_listener AND subscription_register_v2), but the registration/confirmation of payment doesn't complete due to a server error (500) and doesn't release the access in the **ClassyTaxiAppKotlin** app.

Note: **service-account.json** is already configured

Does anyone have any idea why this error is occurring and indicate how I can solve it?

Code where the error points:

```
   private async querySubscriptionPurchaseWithTriggerV2(packageName: string, product: string, purchaseToken: string, triggerNotificationType?: NotificationType): Promise<SubscriptionPurchaseV2> {
     // STEP 1. Query Play Developer API to verify the purchase token
     const apiResponseV2 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this.playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.subscriptionsv2.get({ // <<=== Server error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
         packageName: packageName,
         token: purchaseToken
       }, (err, result) => {
         if (err) {
           reject(this.convertPlayAPIErrorToLibraryError(err));
         } else {
           resolve(result.data);
         }
       })
     });
```

LOGS Firebase Functions

```
6:55:28.798 PM instanceId_register_v2 Function execution started
6:55:31.025 PM instanceId_register_v2 Instance id is ddR1Hi...NOO2Z
6:55:31.122 PM instanceId_register_v2 Instance Id specified and verified
6:55:31.122 PM instanceId_register_v2 Instance verification passed
6:55:31.774 PM instanceId_register_v2 Function execution took 2976 ms, finished with status code: 200

6:55:53.623 PM realtime_notification_listener ========> purchase: null PACKAGE_NAME: com.example.subscriptions
6:55:53.624 PM realtime_notification_listener Function execution took 5 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

6:55:57.537 PM subscription_register_v2 Function execution started
6:55:59.817 PM subscription_register_v2 Server error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
6:55:59.825 PM subscription_register_v2 Function execution took 2289 ms, finished with status code: 500
```

LOGS Android Studio

```
D/OkHttp: --> PUT https://us-central1-postosgnv.cloudfunctions.net/subscription_register_v2 http/1.1 (437-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 500  https://us-central1-postosgnv.cloudfunctions.net/subscription_register_v2 (2661ms, 86-byte body)
E/RemoteServerFunction: Failed to call API (Error code: 500) - {"status":500,"error":"not-found","message":"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"}
```

Comment: Apparently the problem is in the playDeveloperApiClient that is not accepting the purchases.subscriptionsv2.get method, because I tested it using the purchases.subscriptions.get method and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer found [HERE](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/544#issuecomment-1181240976), the issue was solved by updating the GoogleApis package in the package.json from "googleapis": "^67.0.0" -> "googleapis": "105.0.0"